# remoteObjectModel with Angular: Transform get() to dot notation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, remote-objects

I have defined an `<apex:remoteObjectModel>` in my .page file and can access custom objects through `new SObjectModel.ObjectName().retrieve()`. However, the fields in these objects are accessed as

```
object.get("Name")
```

Thus, if I bind this to HTML attributes using Angular, say `ng-bind` or `ng-model` this is not particularly well suited. In particular, I see no appropriate way to bind this to an input text field, etc. Also, this is very verbose. Is there any way or alternative to remote objects that exposes the objects in a way more suitable for Angular?

Comment: Try peeking into object._props property. Should it maybe contain the field values?

Comment: @MLucci Um. Well. Thanks. (embarrassed). Do you want to turn this comment into an answer?

Comment: Not needed - too dirty to be an official one at least... ;)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using AngularJS on Visualforce with RemoteObjects have a look at ngRemote: https://github.com/florianhoehn/ngRemote

It generates angular services for each remote object definition.